# compiling C project with makefile

Tags: c, linux, compilation, compiler-errors, makefile

I have a directory called `reliability`:

```
ls reliability
analyze.c  appl.sh  constr.c  creer.c  greedys.c  Makefile
```

Now I want to install and compile it:

First of all the content of Makefile is:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -pthread

SRCS = constr.c creer.c analyze.c greedys.c
PROG = constr creer analyze greedys

all: $(PROG)

constr: constr.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o constr constr.c

creer: creer.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o creer creer.c

analyze: analyze.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o analyze analyze.c

greedys: greedys.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o greedys greedys.c

clean: 
        rm -f $(PROG)
```

When I start compiling it:

```
make -f Makefile
```

The error occurs:

```
gcc -g -Wall -pthread -o constr constr.c
/tmp/cca4NKQl.o: In function `main':
/home/t1/Desktop/reliability/constr.c:89: undefined reference to `exp'
/home/t1/Desktop/reliability/constr.c:89: undefined reference to `exp'
/home/t1/Desktop/reliability/constr.c:89: undefined reference to `pow'
/home/t1/Desktop/reliability/constr.c:89: undefined reference to `log'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [constr] Error 1
```

I pass these errors by adding `-lm` to gcc,

Even when I change `CFLAGS` from `Makefile` to `CFLAGS = -g -Wall -pthread -lm` there is also that error.

My question:

Should I compile all `.c` programs separately now?

Thank you I really need help,

## UPDATE

When I compile `creer.c` there is an error:

```
creer.c:39:10: warning: unused variable ‘val2’ [-Wunused-variable] creer.c:38:7:
               warning: unused variable ‘val’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

Part of `creer.c` is:

```
void values(){
  int val;
  double val2;
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("instances","r");
  fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
  if(fscanf(fp,"%d",&p)==EOF){printf("EOF\n");}
  if(fscanf(fp,"%d",&m)==EOF){printf("EOF\n");}
  if(fscanf(fp,"%d",&K)==EOF){printf("EOF\n");}
  if(fscanf(fp,"%lf",&lambda_com)==EOF){printf("EOF\n");}
  if(fscanf(fp,"%d",&num_inst)==EOF){printf("EOF\n");}
  if(fscanf(fp,"%d",&boundl)==EOF){printf("EOF\n");}
  if(fscanf(fp,"%d",&boundp)==EOF){printf("EOF\n");}
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Get your compile command working on the command line before putting the CFLAGS to Makefile.

Comment: could you possibly explain me more? I didn't get it, thanks

Comment: google for `undefined reference to 'exp' math.h` reveals possible duplicate of [Undefined reference to exp on Ubuntu (including math.h and linking with -lm)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492064/undefined-reference-to-exp-on-ubuntu-including-math-h-and-linking-with-lm)

Comment: Yes it has: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>`

Comment: There are warnings about unused variables. Not errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add that linker option `-lm` to the end of your command line.

Do something like this:

```
LDFLAGS=-lm

...

constr: constr.c    
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o constr constr.c $(LDFLAGS)
```

Or you could define a pattern rule:

```
%: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS)
```

and use it to replace all those rules for constr, creer, and so on.

Comment: for doing first solution...just adding first line and add `$(LDFLAGS)` is enough you think?

Comment: I am really thankful... one more question, is this error critical for running apps? (`creer.c:39:10: warning: unused variable ‘val2’ [-Wunused-variable]
creer.c:38:7: warning: unused variable ‘val’ [-Wunused-variable])`

Comment: @MortezaLSC Those unused variables should not cause any run time problem.